# How to scrape queried web data using rvest?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

As an example, I would like to scrape store information from this website: http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/store-locator.html

In the search by bar, I type in "Toronto" and a list comes up.

Here's what I normally do with simple websites:

```
link=html("http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/store-locator.html")
link %>% html_nodes("#container > div.clearfix > div.parbase.container.sl-closest-location-container > div.sl-closest-location-container__inner > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sl-closest-location-container__store-name.sl-closest-location-container__active > span.sl-closest-location-container__item-name") %>% html_text()
```

I have tried a couple CSS codes, nothing seemed to work. Please help.

Comment: It returns the parsed html document

Comment: i'm really unfamiliar with this, i thought those two were the same thing?

Comment: Can you add an example showing what you are confused about?

Comment: the reason I ask is because i'm having trouble scraping data from queried results, such as store locations from http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/store-locator.html; @RichardScriven do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Well, it's quite a bit of work.  Perhaps you should consider revising the question to go into detail about what you are attempting to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you, I edited the question to make it more concrete. I would still like to understand the difference between the source code and the parsed html document if anyone is patient enough to explain

Comment: The underlying search call is `http://www.canadiantire.ca/services/canadian-tire/search-store?from=toronto&lat=43.653226&lng=-79.38318429999998&maxCount=10&storeType=store&locale=en&_=1440562490202` which returns JSON you can use. That URL can be tweaked to find other location in other areas.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thank you! how did you find this url?

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, I played around with the developer tools but am still pretty clueless, would it be too complicated to briefly explain the process?

Comment: http://rud.is/dl/ctiredevtools.gif is a short/small-ish animated gif showing how to do this

Comment: @hrbrmstr wow thank you so much you are amazing